# filter time stamp to date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I'm using Stripe and the way stripe returns the start and end dates for a subscription are in timestamp such as this

```
current_period_start: 1465271767
current_period_end: 1433649367
```

I'm using angular for the presentation layer. Is there a way to convert this time stamp to short date like June 7, 2015?

right now I'm displaying the date like this and it always displays `Jan 17, 1970`

```
<td>{{x.current_period_start | date:short }}</td>
```

Answer (score 4):

Unix timestamps are in seconds and JavaScript uses milliseconds. Multiply the start and end date values by 1000. Those dates will result in  `Mon Jun 06 2016 22:56:07 GMT-0500 (CDT)` and `Sat Jun 06 2015 22:56:07 GMT-0500 (CDT)` respectively.

Untested but this should work in your view:

```
<td>{{x.current_period_start * 1000 | date:short }}</td>
```